# Overwriting soft delete table column for a model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using laravel 5.4.

I have a model that points to a database table that has the following attributes.

```
id       integer
name     varchar
location varchar
deleted  boolean
```

This is an old table and due to it being entwined in a bunch of code we can't change this table.

What I want to do is take advantage of laravels soft delete functionality within a model.  I know that laravel expects the column name to be `deleted_at` and the data type to be `date` on the database table.

How do I override this so this so that Laravel will look at the column `deleted` and check if it's a `boolean`?

I've tried looking at the classes that my model inherits from but haven't been able to find where the constant and function that handles this is defined. I suspect it might be on the collection but have had no luck.

Ideally I would like to simply redefine the functions in my model.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look into the [`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/SoftDeletes.php) trait and override `runSoftDelete()` and `getDeletedAtColumn` methods in the model.

In `runSoftDelete()` use `boolean` instead of timestamp and in `getDeletedAtColumn()` use `DELETED` instead of `DELETED_AT`

Another solution is adding [global scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#global-scopes) or [local scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#local-scopes) to work with soft deleted data.

Comment: The `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingScope` class queries based on the trashed column being not null. A boolean `false` would then be regarded as being trashed, since it's not null. You may need to accommodate that as well.

Comment: @JohnEllmore that's true, thanks. I guess the easiest way to do that is to make the `deleted` nullable. In this case, OP will not need to override 3 more methods to make `boolean` work. @hdifen if you can't make it `nullable` and don't want to override so many methods, consider creating your own trait. I'm pretty sure you don't need all the soft deletes related functionality Laravel provides, so the trait can be super simple.

Comment: Hey, So I think that trait is primarily for when you want a model that only has the deleted columns. It adds a 'WHERE NULL' statement to my queries.  I can overwrite some of the functions to allow me to delete models with it but when retrieving items I still run into the problem of it giving me back deleted items. @JohnEllmore What is the starting point for me to do your solution?  I'm not sure how to make a model only get items where 'deleted = 0'

Comment: I don't actually have a solution that I was suggesting :) I was just pointing out a potential problem. @Alexey Mezenin's suggestion of making your own trait is a good starting point. Or consider abandoning Laravel's built-in soft delete functionality, and instead implement it using Eloquent query scopes. You could introduce a global query scope that hides deleted models by default, for instance.

Comment: @hdifen the easiest way to handle this is to create a [local scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#local-scopes). Then you'll be able to add something like `->withoutDeleted()` to your queries.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Awesome, you put me on the right path. The solution I used was to add an anonymous global scope with `$builder->where('deleted', 0);`. Thanks!  If I want to be able to use the `delete()` method I will probably have to overwrite that method in my model. If you answer pointing a link to the anonymous global scopes I'll accept it.

Comment: FYI my first comment was wrong. I had a misunderstanding on how the softdeletes trait worked.